# SQL - Limit results on groups

Tags: sql, syntax, group-by, sql-order-by, having

I have the following table :

```
Car      | color    | year
---------+----------+------
mercedes | blue     | 1991
mercedes | yellow   | 1993
mercedes | blue     | 1996
mercedes | red      | 1998
renaud   | blue     | 1991
renaud   | yellow   | 1993
renaud   | blue     | 1996
renaud   | red      | 1998
```

I am looking for a query which permits to retrieve the oldest year row of each car type.
In this case, it should give me :

```
Car       | color | year
----------+-------+------
mercedes  | blue  | 1991
renaud    | blue  | 1991
```

I have tried with ORDER BY + LIMIT, HAVING, GROUP BY.... But it always add extra rows which I don't need (I have to iterate over the result set to create a sub result).

Do you have ideas of how I could do that ?

Thanks a lot for your helpfull hints !

Kheraud

Comment: How is a 1991 blue Mercedes more "recent" than a 1996 blue Mercedes? I don't follow how you're trying to group the results...

Comment: agreed - example is incorrect...

Comment: Did you mean "oldest" instead of "more recent"? If two cars with different color are both from equally more recent (or older or whatever the criterion really is), what should the result be?

Comment: Sorry for bad english, I meant oldest in fact...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nested select - something like this:

```
select car, max(year) yr
from mytable
group by car
```

this gives the proper year for each car.  then you want to add a color (not specified what to do if there are more than one in that year for that car...)

```
select a.car, a.color, a.yr
from (
select car, max(year) yr
from mytable
group by car
) a
, mytable
where mytable.car = a.car
and mytable.year = a.yr
```

Answer (score 0):

select car, color, Max(Year) from table_name
group by car,color